# Axios post to nodejs server but nodejs cannot get data

Tags: express, vue.js, axios

i post from vuejs cli with axios to nodejs express server:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8081/users', bar)
        .then((response)=> {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          console.log(error)
        })
```

and server:

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.bar)
  res.json(req.body.bar)
})
```

in http://localhost:8081/users i got `Cannot GET /users` and console log windows: undefined

please help me!

Comment: Does the server has a GET method? I'm not familiar with NodeJS or Axios, but I guess your server doesn't listen to GET requests, only POST.

Comment: app.get('/') only and it run

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8081/users', {foo: "Bar"})
 .then((response)=> {
      console.log(response.data) // must be show "Bar"
  })
  .catch((error)=> {
      console.log(error)
  })

app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.foo) // must be show "Bar"
  res.send(req.body.foo)
})
```